# Que signifie « elle seule et entièrement » ?

Tags: sens, philosophie

[image]

Voici un extrait du livre *Introduction à la philosophie de l'histoire* de Raymond Aron.
Je pense que l'auteur a omis certains contenus dans cette phrase « elle seule et entièrement », mais je n'arrive pas à le déterminer.
elle = classe ? société ?

Comment: Il ne manque pas forcément de mots, je pense que ça peut se comprendre mais là encore il faut une formation à la pensée de Aron pour l'expliquer, c'est du langage philosophique et les mots et concepts ont des valeurs avec lesquels il faut être familier.   Et s'il manquait des mots ce ne serait pas une omission de l'auteur (Araon a été édité et commenté de long en large depuis longtemps) mais de l'édition particulière que tu as sous les yeux.

Comment: Livre: "La philosophie de l'histoire" avec un l majuscule. [Je pense qu'Aron]. Il me semble que l'antecédent ici, c'est le mot totalité. [...] qui l'exprimerait, c'est à dire, la totalité. Je pense qu'il n'y a pas des mots qui manquent. Exprimer la totalité en elle-même et entièrement.

Comment: Merci pour votre correction.

Comment: @Lambie — Les constructions sinueuses d'une pensée qui se plait dans la complication produit des phrases absconses. La *totalité* remplacerait la *vérité* de la phrase précédente alors que la *classe* est rattachée à la *société* ? Pour un r***é***sonnement pseudo mathématicien, c'est celle dernière, *la société dans son entièreté* qui est induite dans le *elle*, puisque la *classe* ne convient pas à l'auteur comme variable de référence.

Comment: @林剑锋 — La soi-disante “prétention de Lukacs” est vérifiée aujourd'hui par la ***classe** financière et les GAFAM*. Ayant eu R. Aron au programme il y a plus de cinquante ans, je n'ai jamais dépassé le premier chapitre de « Paix et Guerre entre les nations » tant son écriture est absconse, le prof' nous disait que ce livre n'était pas “digéré” par Aron : pour être compréhensible il aurait dû être de trois à quatre fois moins volumineux (sic)… ce qui ne m'a pas empêché de réussir mon concours d'entrée !

Comment: @Simon … merci de voter pour l'inintelligibilité du texte. J'aimerais savoir combien d'académies mettent encore l'auteur à leur programme !

Comment: @Simon — Alors ce serait la classe  "elle seule et entièrement" que la société exprimerait [cette classe et pas les autres] ? ou, la société qui exprime la classe  "elle seule et entièrement", mis après une virgule en incise pour valider la conclusion ? [dans les deux cas c'est un raisonnement bancal qui rejette ce que son point de vue ne peut percevoir] ?

Comment: @Simon … alors c'est la construction du château en Espagne, aucune société n'est faite d'une seule classe… ce doit être cela qui m'empêche de lire plus loin… il est possible que je me trompe, mais 林剑锋  reste sur sa faim :-(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132439/discussion-between-personne-and-simon).

Comment: J’interpréterais ceci par une figure de style où une classe, une société endoctrinée, formatée serait décrite par "elle seule" et "entièrement" vu qu'il s'agit dans ce cas d'une multitude de personnes qui font "entièrement" partie de cette classe.
C'est un point de vue très discutable à la première lecture. Même si selon lui (Raymond Aron) "Le Capital de Karl Marx est un livre très long, très austère et très scientifique".
Aron fait déjà probablement référence à une société marxiste, à une entité seule et unique ou "pensée entière" dans ce cas...
Bien à vous.

Answer (score 1):

je peux comprendre son propos dans le sens suivant :

je crois qu'il parle de **la vérité de l'histoire** qui ne peut être **une** (vérité) que s'il n'y a pas plusieurs classes d'individus qui en expriment des versions différentes. C'est d'ailleurs ce que rappelle sa phrase suivante.
Pour que cette classe d'individus *qui crée l'histoire* puisse faire émerger  une unique vérité et pouvoir la penser, il lui faudra observer une société qui exprime cette version unique, **elle seule et entièrement** (sinon ce n'est plus unique ni complet)

Answer (score -2):

Je ne vois pas votre problème: ''Elle seule = cette société bien définie et elle seule (aucune autre) le ferait (résoudrait le problème) complètement. Les deux mots ''elle'' et ''entièrement'' se complètent donc.                   Exemple: ''Le probléme algérien n'a pu être réglée, en 1962, que par une seule personne compétente (= dans le texte présent: une seule société) et celle-ci l'a réglé complètement, pour de bon.''

Comment: En dehors du manque de respect pour la personne non francophone qui a posé la question contenu dans « Je ne vois pas votre problème », on a du mal à comprendre ce que vient faire l'exemple de la guerre d'Algérie dans cette explication.